# Novel series with students at a magic university

Tags: story-identification, novel, books, wizards

I read two books in a series and have forgotten the author and the titles.

The first book was about a young man who was a student in a magic university who became very powerful and was able to travel to different worlds.

I think the second book was about a young woman who painted and had magical powers.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/190325/ya-fantasy-about-a-girl-being-turned-into-a-book-by-a-magician?

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/35713410-blackwood?

Comment: Perhaps Raymond E Feist's Magician as the first (although I'm not sure the second matches any others in that series ... I've only read the first few, and don't remember a character Like the one described).